# Getting a Connection failed error when deploying an API

Tags: postgresql, api, sqlalchemy, alembic

In the development environment I am not getting any errors but when deploying the same API on UBUNTU OR HEROKU I am getting an connection failed error

Where's my database file where I am connecting to the database using sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
import time
from .config import settings

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f'postgresql://{settings.database_username}:{settings.database_password}@{settings.database_hostname}:{settings.database_port}/{settings.database_name}'


engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()


def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

Alembic env.py file

```
config.set_main_option(
    "sqlalchemy.url", f'postgresql+psycopg2://{settings.database_username}:{settings.database_password}@{settings.database_hostname}:{settings.database_port}/{settings.database_name}')
```

I tired deploying it on ubuntu and heroku both are giving me the same connection error IDK why

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with FastAPI. Are you sure your database is on the same host & port on the environments in which it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, It's on the same port and host but still it doesnt work

Comment: Please complete your question with an error message.